# x86_64-linux-musl-g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory, on alpine container

Tags: c++, docker, gcc, cross-compiling, musl

I am having a problem compiling C/C++ code on an alpine (and ubuntu) container with MUSL toolchain (http://musl.cc/x86_64-linux-musl-cross.tgz )

The error is seen when the container is run on a CentOS workstation (and also Ubuntu)

```
[user@centoshost ~]# uname -a
Linux centoshost 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 29 14:59:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[user@centoshost ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Release:        7.6.1810
Codename:       Core
[user@centoshost ~]#
```

The same container image when run on an Ubuntu 18.04/CentOS 7 VM (Oracle VirtualBox) is able to compile. The docker version is same (18.09.5) on VM and the workstation.

The error:

```
bash-5.1# /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++ -v test.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++
Target: x86_64-linux-musl
Configured with: ../src_gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran CC='gcc -static --static' CXX='g++ -static --static' FC='gfortran -static --static' CFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' CXXFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' FFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' LDFLAGS='-s -static --static' --enable-default-pie --enable-static-pie --disable-bootstrap --disable-assembly --disable-werror --target=x86_64-linux-musl --prefix= --libdir=/lib --disable-multilib --with-sysroot=/x86_64-linux-musl --enable-tls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --disable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-libmpx --enable-libstdcxx-time=rt --enable-deterministic-archives --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-decimal-float --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_sysroot AR_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/ar AS_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/gas/as-new LD_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/ld/ld-new NM_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/nm-new OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/objcopy OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/objdump RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/ranlib READELF_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/readelf STRIP_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/strip-new --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 'CC_FOR_BUILD=cc -static --static' 'CXX_FOR_BUILD=g++ -static --static'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.1 20210116 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 cc1plus -quiet -v -iprefix /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/ -isysroot /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../x86_64-linux-musl -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/ccDckJiL.s
x86_64-linux-musl-g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried adding the path to cc1plus to PATH env variable. For this i got a different error:

```
bash-5.1# PATH=$PATH:/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/
bash-5.1# /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++ -v test.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++
Target: x86_64-linux-musl
Configured with: ../src_gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran CC='gcc -static --static' CXX='g++ -static --static' FC='gfortran -static --static' CFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' CXXFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' FFLAGS='-g0 -O2 -fno-align-functions -fno-align-jumps -fno-align-loops -fno-align-labels' LDFLAGS='-s -static --static' --enable-default-pie --enable-static-pie --disable-bootstrap --disable-assembly --disable-werror --target=x86_64-linux-musl --prefix= --libdir=/lib --disable-multilib --with-sysroot=/x86_64-linux-musl --enable-tls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --disable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-libmpx --enable-libstdcxx-time=rt --enable-deterministic-archives --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-decimal-float --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_sysroot AR_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/ar AS_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/gas/as-new LD_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/ld/ld-new NM_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/nm-new OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/objcopy OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/objdump RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/ranlib READELF_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/readelf STRIP_FOR_TARGET=/tmp/m1032/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_binutils/binutils/strip-new --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 'CC_FOR_BUILD=cc -static --static' 'CXX_FOR_BUILD=g++ -static --static'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.1 20210116 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 cc1plus -quiet -v -iprefix /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/ -isysroot /x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../x86_64-linux-musl -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/ccogMFKi.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 10.2.1 20210116 (x86_64-linux-musl)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1/x86_64-linux-musl"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1/x86_64-linux-musl"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include/c++/10.2.1/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../x86_64-linux-musl/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../x86_64-linux-musl/usr/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/10.2.1/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
End of search list.
cc1plus: fatal error: test.cpp: Operation not permitted
compilation terminated.
```

I am running as root and 'test.cpp' has 644 permissions.

---

Found some solutions for the issue.

Running the Alpine Container as "privileged" solved the issue with the musl toolchain.
Also the previous version of the musl toolchain (Released in January 2021), did not give me the issue.